# Can "go with" be used as "suggest"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The dialog from Casino Royale movie looks a bit strange for me:

> Now, I'd have normally
>   gone with only child
>   but, you see, by the way you ignored
>   the quip about your parents
>   I'm gonna have to go with orphan.

Dictionary says that "to be" can be used:

> To select or choose: *decided to go with the pink wallpaper*.

But, in the movie, James Bond doesn't choose or decide, he suggest if I understand context correctly. He could have spoken "I'd have normally suggested you are the only child", with same meaning, isn't it?

Comment: Someone who doesn't have the authority to make the final choice may ***suggest** option **X***. The person who *does* have that authority may ***go with / choose** that option* (OR he may choose something else). The difference between ***suggest** (possible choice)* and ***choose** (actual choice)* should be clear.

Comment: ...but note that Bond is talking about ***choosing*** which "guess" he's going to "suggest" correctly describes the other person's background.

Answer (score 2):

In the movie, Bond is trying to guess Vesper's background just by looking at her.  This goes with your definition of "to choose"; in this case it means "to pick one of the possible options".   Vesper could be many things, but Bond is choosing *to guess* that she is an orphan.

It can be used in a suggestion, but it doesn't suggest anything by itself:

> I recommend you go with the blue suit, ma'am.
>
> I suggest we go with Foxtrot Communications to set up our network.

And so on.

Comment: Thank you very much. I asked a question as _Can “go with” be used as __suggest___, and this is my big mistake because of the small vocabulary. I actually meant _Can “go with” mean guess_ (not suggest), or assume, suppose. Anyway, your answer made it totally clear for me.